# Custom View: Canvas draw methods give API error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-canvas, android-view

I created a custom view and overrode the `onDraw` method.

However, Android Studio says my `canvas.drawOval` and `canvas.drawArc` calls require I set my minimum API to 21.

Canvas has been around since API 1 right?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Button;

public class PieButton extends Button {

    float progress = 0f;

    public PieButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(0xFF00C853);  
        canvas.drawOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(0xFF000000);
        canvas.drawArc(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 0f, progress*(-360), true, paint);
    }

    public void setProgress (float inputProgress) {
        progress = inputProgress;
    }
}
```

The error message I get is:

> Call requires API level 21 (current min is 16): android.graphics.Canvas#drawOval less... (Ctrl+F1)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The drawOval() method that you are using from canvas was added in API 21.

**`public void drawOval (float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Paint paint)`** - API 21.

You should try using the drawOval() with  RectF parameter, instead.

**`public void drawOval (RectF oval, Paint paint)`** - API 1

Same applies for drawArc(). Use drawArc with RectF parameter.

**`public void drawArc (RectF oval, float startAngle, float sweepAngle, boolean useCenter, Paint paint)`** - API 1

Answer (score 0):

`canvas.drawOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);` is being added in API level 21. See API call [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawOval(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)).

If you want to draw oval at api level minimum than 21 you should use it in following way,

```
RectF rect=new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

public void drawOval (rect, paint);
```